# On the dimension of tangents spaces of smooth manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, matrix-rank, tangent-spaces

Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ be a smooth $m$-dimensional manifold and fix a point $p$ on $M$.

Let $U_0 \subset M$ be an $M$-open set with $p \in U_0$ and let $\phi_0 : U_0 → \Omega_0$
be a diffeomorphism onto an open subset $Ω_0 ⊂ \mathbb{R}^m$.

Define $x_0 := \phi_0(p)$ and let $\psi_0 := \phi_0^{-1}: \Omega_0 \rightarrow U_0$ be the inverse map. Then:

$$T_pM = (\text{im  }d\psi_0(x_0): \mathbb{}  \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k) $$

An inclusion argument is trivial to make, i.e. for a small enough $t$ and $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^m$, such that $x_0 + t \xi \in \Omega_0$, we can define a curve $\gamma: (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \rightarrow M$, such that $\gamma(t) := \psi_0(x_0 + t\xi)$. Naturally, we get:

$$\gamma(0) = p, \text{ } \dot{\gamma}(0) = \frac{d}{dt} \bigg|_{t=0} \psi_0(x_0 + t\xi) = d\psi_0(x_0) \xi$$

This shows that $d\psi_0\xi \in T_pM$, which is all fine. The author then goes to say that since $\dim \text{im  }d\psi_0(x_0) = m$, the problem is solved.

I'm missing the justification behind this $\dim \text{im  }d\psi_0(x_0) = m$. Indeed, given the smoothness of $\psi_0 := \phi_0^{-1}$ I assume some argument can be made regarding the rank/surjectivity of the Jacobian $d\psi(x_0)$ via some form of the inverse function theorem, but I just can't get my finger on it.

Otherwise, regarding $d\psi(x_0)$ as the best linear approximation to $\psi$ around $x_0$, one may write:

$$\psi(x_0 + t \xi) = \psi(x_0) + td\psi(x_0)\xi + o(\Vert \xi \Vert)$$

But given $m \neq k$ I find it non-trivial to argue for the surjectivity of $d\psi(x_0)$.
A solution would be welcome.

The text I'm studying is [Introduction to Differential Geometry, Robin and Salamon](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Esalamon/PREPRINTS/diffgeo.pdf) (18 April 2020 version), page 26.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We follow J. Milnor, *Topology from the differentiable viewpoint*, page 5, almost verbatim.

Since $\phi_0\colon U_0\to\Omega_0$ is a smooth mapping, we can choose an open set $W$ containing $p$ and a smooth map $F\colon W\to\mathbf{R}^m$ that coincides with $\phi_0$ on $W\cap U_0$. Letting $V=\phi_0(W\cap U_0)$ and writing $\iota\colon V\to\mathbf{R}^m$ for the inclusion map, we have $\iota=F\circ\psi_0$ and therefore $\text{id}_{\mathbf{R}^m}=dF_p\circ d(\psi_0)_{x_0}$. It follows that $d(\psi_0)_{x_0}$ has rank $m$, and hence its image $T_pM$ has dimension $m$.